# Show that every nontrivial subgroup of $G$ contains $\frac{1}{p} + \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be the Prüfer $p$-group $:=\left \{ \frac{a}{p^n}+\mathbb{Z}:a,n \in \mathbb{Z},n\geq0 \right \}$, for some prime $p$. Show that every nontrivial
> subgroup of $G$ contains $\frac{1}{p} + \mathbb{Z}$.

I am not sure how to start with this exercise. It occurs to me that being a divisible group, the element $\frac{1}{p} + \mathbb{Z}$ is related in some way to the elements of the subgroup and therefore contained in it. Any hint?

Comment: Well if it's nontrivial it must contain some nonzero element $\frac{a}{p^n}+Z$ where $a$ does not divide $p$, and hence it contains $\frac{a}{p}+Z$. Now $a$ has a multiplicative inverse mod $p$, etc.

Comment: @DerekHolt Why exactly $a/p^n+\mathbb{Z}$ lies in the subgroup? It's not very clear to me. Also, what about the multiplicative inverse?

Comment: The subgroup is nonempty, so it must contain an element that is not equal to the identity. I was just writing that element as $\frac{a}{p^n} + Z$. The fact that it is not the identity means that $p$ does not divide $a$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh, I understand. But I still don't understand the multiplicative inverse. I know that if $(a, p) =1$ then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$, But I don't know how to use it here. I know I am very pretentious, but this is my first encounter with this subject. I would appreciate your help very much

Comment: For example, suppow that $p=7$ and $a=3$, so $\frac{3}{7} + Z$ is in the subgroup $H$. The multiplicative inverse of $3$ mod $7$ is $5$ (because $5 \times 3 \equiv 1 \bmod 7$), and then we have $5(\frac{3}{7} + Z) = \frac{1}{7} + Z \in H$.